# What does this error mean?

Tags: support

There is a red bar at the top of the screen that says:

> Travel Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

[image]

It came out of nowhere and then disappeared

Comment: Maybe post this on Meta.SE?

Answer (score 1):

It means it couldn't access ajax.googleapis.com temporarily. I get that every day as I whitelist external links from a site.

Comment: You get it too if you're not using a VPN in China.